# Split string by specific html tags with keeping tags

Tags: python, html

I need to split string by specific number of tags `(<li>, <lu> ...)`. I came up with regex

`pattern = <li>|<ul>|<ol>|<li>|<dl>|<dt>|<dd>|<h1>|<h2>|<h3>|<h4>|<h5>|<h6>` and `re.split`

Basically  it does the job

```
test_string = '<p> Some text some text some text. </p> <p> Another text another text </p>. <li> some list </li>. <ul> another list </ul>'
res = re.search(test_string, pattern) 
-> `['<p> Some text some text some text. </p> <p> Another text another text </p>. ', ' some list </li>. ', ' another list </ul>']`
```

But i would like to capture both opening and closing tags and keep tags in splitted text. Something like

```
['<p> Some text some text some text. </p> <p> Another text another text </p>. ', '<li> some list </li>. ', '<ul>another list </ul>']`
```

Comment: Don't use string and regex operations to manipulate HTML. Use a DOM parser (e.g. BeautifulSoup in Python).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question:

```
<(p|li|ul|ol|dl|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6)>[^<]*</\1>
```

and Match rather than split.

`\1` refers to what's captured in the opening tag.

Something like:

```
for match in re.finditer(r"<(p|li|ul|ol|dl|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6)>[^<]*</\1>", subject, re.DOTALL):
```

However, in most *real* situations this will be insufficient to work with HTML and you should think about a DOM Parser.